# When M-x desktop-read, theme elements incorrectly restored / displayed: previous theme saved into desktop file?

Tags: spacemacs, themes

I'm a new Emacs user, and I've come across a quirk:

I use a light theme during the day, and I've configured `theme-changer` to switch to a dark theme after sundown; it works wonders.

However, when I quit Emacs, it saves my desktop session (open buffers, etc.), including the theme that was active during the session.

When I invoke `M-x desktop-read`, the previous session is restored, but theme elements aren't correctly displayed.
Example: light theme elements, saved with the session, mixed with dark theme (active later when restoring dession).

*Example:*

**Restored session using** `M-x desktop-read`**: dark-theme is currently ON, session was saved using light-theme**
[image: Restored session using <code>M-x desktop-read</code>]

**Restored session, using dark-theme: expected behavior**
[image: Restored session, using dark-theme: expected behavior]

Does anybody know a way to tell Emacs not save the active theme in the desktop file, or to load everything *but* the theme active at that time, so that the current theme prevails?

Comment: Further example:

I was working under the `spacemacs-light` theme, and after sundown, `theme-changer` switched the theme to `spacemacs-dark`.

See here how the dark theme retains light-colored elements from the previous theme?


https://imgur.com/a/J70p4

Comment: ...** bump **...

Comment: Do you need to use `desktop.el`?  What do you need it for?

Comment: I use Spacemacs, which includes `desktop.el` in its layers.
It looks pleasing, and it is an aesthetical factor.

Comment: I use spacemacs too but I don't use desktop.el, because after a long time using it I found it tended to cause me a lot of problems.  desktop.el does not provide any aesthetic (visual) stuff at all, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Your input doesn't really address the question.

Comment: That's why it's a comment.  Just trying to help...